# How do I get rid of odd bytes from this output?

Tags: linux, bash, sed

So, for my statistics class, I've been using a lot of linux trickery to organize my numbers, copy/paste them around, etc. Now, I haven't had any issues until just recently... I had copy pasted a bunch of values out of Open Office (could be the culprit), and was trying to format them like so...

```
echo "5  8  6  25  4  21  10  1  24  12  4  16  
9  2  12  28  14  17  12  1  16  18  18  3  
12  6  6  12  10  20  9  6  8  6  8  15" | sed 's/\s\+/\n/g' | grep -v ^$ | sed 's/[[:space:]]*$//g' > test.txt
```

This would put each number on it's own line just fine, but when I pasted into statdisk, I was getting some invalid character errors. It APPEARED to be a space, but I tried using sed and tr with varations on [:space:], [:blank:], and things like s/[ \t]*$//g to try and remove whatever was trailing at the end (which I could delete just fine in Vim). But nothing on the CLI worked.

Running a hexdump on that file gives me

```
5   �   �  \n   8   �   �  \n   6   �   �  \n   2   5   �   �
```

What the heck are those? hexdump -C

```
35 c2 a0 0a 38 c2 a0 0a  36 c2 a0 0a 32 35 c2 a0  |5...8...6...25..|
```

Anyone have any idea what those c2 a0 bytes are? Is there an easy/elegant way to nuke them with sed or tr or something? Or being non-ascii would I need to do something clever with byte manipulation... Any thoughts/suggestions?

Comment: Are the strange characters in your OpenOffice output file? I remember Calc was pretty good at some number fiddling, but I don't know if it's got a `sed` interface/plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`c2a0` is UTF-8 [U+00A0](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm), NO-BREAK SPACE. You could easily use `tr` to remove them, e.g.,

```
> echo -n $'5\u00a0 8\u00a0 6' | tr -d $'\u00a0' | xxd
00000000: 3520 3820 36                             5 8 6
```

Note that the `\u` escape only works in Bash 4.2+, but of course you could replace with `$'\xc2\xa0'`.

Comment: What does the $'string' do? I know $(command) for command substitution, that replaces the depracated backtick, but I don't know the difference between $'\u00a0' and "\u00a0"

Comment: ANSI-C quoting. https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting.

Comment: Aha, thank you for that. It seems to me like many utilities do this automatically? Good to know that I can do it right in the shell though, for utilities that might not parse them out right.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "many utilities do this automatically". What utilities are you talking about? Example? At least standard *ix utilities shouldn't treat U+00A0 differently than any other random codepoint. The POSIX blank character class in full unicode range might include this character, but that's as far as how special it is.

Comment: By the way, does this answer solve your problem? If so, you may accept it; if it doesn't, say what you want exactly.

Comment: I tried to accept it, as it does work (I had to do the /xc2/xa0 version), but I don't have enough rep over here yet =/ And by "many utilities do this automatically" I mean that usually when I type things like \n, or \t, they're recognized as newline or horizontal tab without me needing to do $'\n' or whatever.

Comment: As I was reading up on sed, I discovered a trick I THOUGHT might work... Doing `sed -r 's/([0-9]+) (.*)/\1/g'` to find only the numbers, and print those, disregarding anything else matched on the line. However, it still leaves the no-break spaces in when I try it this way. Any idea why that may be?

Comment: You don't need rep to accept an answer to *your* question... (And you can't accept an answer on other people's questions whatever your rep is, for that matter.) There's a checkmark to the left of the answer. Click that.

Comment: Re sed: Your regex doesn't mean what you probably want it to mean. Try https://regex101.com/ for an explanation of what it really does. What you can use is `sed -r 's/([[:digit:]]+)[^[:digit:]]+/\1 /g'`

Comment: Too make it even easier for you: here's the explanation of your regex: https://regex101.com/r/gO0aK2/1. And here's mine: https://regex101.com/r/gO0aK2/2.

Comment: Aha, thanks again for those resources. I apparently tried to "upvote" your answer, not accept it, thus the rep error. Derp.

Comment: Seems I missed one of your earlier comments about utilities. No, this is different. If you type a no-break space into the command line it won't be treated as a whitespace. The only whitespace characters are SPACE, TAB, LF, and CR. Sure you can redefine your word separator IFS to include Unicode blanks, but it's not the default and not recommended, and it won't help here either because the no/break spaces are in double quotes.